# Launch streamlit application under azure databricks

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, streamlit, azure-virtual-network

I would like to run a small streamlit app under Azure Databricks (running from Databricks cluster web terminal). When I try to run it throught the command ***streamlit run foo_script.py***, I get two differents URLs, one network and the other one for external access. None of them seem to work (access denied).

Then, inside Microsoft Azure, I create a virtual network, two subnets and a network security group associated with the subnets. Also, under the network security group, I create inbound and outbound rules to enable some specific ports.

Anyway, none of these actions solve the problem and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

The network security group is automatically created from the Azure Databricks service creation interface (Network tab). I tried to create my own network security group, but nothing changes.

Below, I show the network topology through the Azure Network Watcher service.

[Network topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN0Wc.png)

Answer (score 0):

I created Databricks to run streamlit app like below:

[image]

To run streamlit app used below commands:

```
pip install streamlit
```

[image]

Now, when I run below command, I got URL successfully like below:

```
!streamlit run /databricks/python_shell/scripts/db_ipykernel_launcher.py
```

[image]

To run this URL, ensure that you need to add port `8501` like below:

[image]

As suggested by *Akshay_127877*, using Databricks-cli on my streamlit app, run the Databricks notebooks and store the app on github and to launch the app in github use Azure app services refer [this](https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/how-to-open-streamlit-url-that-is-hosted-by-databricks-in-local/td-p/7339)

Comment: Thank you Imran, but it still does not work. I have Databricks created with a virtual network and private subnet.

The subnet configuration includes the address range (which accepts the streamlit app IP address) and a network security group that includes an inbound security rule (priority 100) with the ports 8501-8509 with the same options as you mentioned.

Anyway, when I run either **streamlit run foo_script.py** or **streamlit run /databricks/python_shell/scripts/db_ipykernel_launcher.py** from the cluster web terminal, the URLs are generated but not reachable.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Modify the app to bind to the IP address of the network interface that is accessible from external sources. You can do this by adding the following line of code to your Streamlit app streamlit run foo_script.py --server.address 0.0.0.0 --server.port 8501
once you bind the app to the IP address "0.0.0.0 it will be accessible from any network interface, and port 8501 Try running it again from the cluster web terminal and see if you are able to access it from external sources.